# How short can we state the Axiom of Choice?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

How short can we state a principle which is equivalent with the Axiom of Choice under $ZF$? The principle should be a sentence in the language of set theory with only $\in$ and$=$ as extralogical relation signs; I thus disregard solutions that appeal to selectors as the epsilon operator. My motivation is to extend an interpretation of $ZF$ to one of $ZFC$, and a short sentence schema will make my work - simpler and shorter.

Update: On the basis of comments I have developed an answer with a challenge as to whether we may improve.

Comment: Can you give just one example of a solution that you *wouldn't* disregard, whether long or not or simple or not?

Comment: I don't understand the import of your question, Todd. Clearly, AC is an exmple of a statement which is equivalent with AC under ZF. Thomas Jech wrote a book about equivalents of the Axiom of Choice which I do not have available, and there may be others since and here that have had a special interest in these matters.

Comment: I didn't understand what you were driving at with "solutions that appeal to selection operators and their kins". It's the word 'kin' that seems vague -- is Paul's suggestion something you would disregard?

Comment: I conjecture that the selection operators that you want to exclude are things like Hilbert's epsilon operator (also known as Bourbaki's tau operator) that are built into the language and thus try to make AC part of the underlying logic. In other words, I conjecture that you would not object to a formulation asserting, in the usual language of set theory, the existence of some sort of selection function.

Comment: The simplest statement for motivational purposes seems to me to be that the Cartesian product of any family of nonempty sets is nonempty.  You are unlikely, on first run-through, to hear anyone speak up in opposition to that.  (Of course, there are selection operators under the hood but ..)

Comment: Andreas is on the spot; I was thinking about selectors such as the epsilon operator. 

Paul's suggestion does not fit my criteria as it is not in the language of set theory. Francois gives a solution, but can we not do much better?

Comment: It seems to me that François' solution is near optimal, considering that all usual equivalents of AC (which are gather in Rubin & Rubin's book rather than in Jech's), use notions which, when unwound in the language, are considerably larger.

Comment: @Godelian I very much appreciate your remark. But let us wait some and see if someone comes up with something shorter.

Comment: Even if Paul's suggestion is not expressed in the *formal* language of ZF, it's quite obvious how one would go about rewriting it in that language, and moreover: it's *conceptually* very simple. This raises the question of what is meant by "simplicity" in the Original Post. Or are we just counting the number of symbols in a ZF formula?

Comment: @Todd Trimble I clearly indicated shortness as a criterion, and my motivation is  expressed. My interest concerning this is indeed concerned with how these matters are cashed out in the formal language of set theory, and you are no doubt right in that there may be conceptually simpler principles to be had than those that best fit what I am looking for.

Comment: Okay, thanks Frode. As a friendly suggestion: please consider editing your question to take into account Andreas's (correct) conjecture, and please consider removing the word "simple" (or "simply") since that's not so easy to measure, and specify shortness as the desired criterion. I think you then want to specify that you are looking for formulae written in the formal language of ZF -- in that case I think the question becomes crystal clear.

Comment: @Todd Thanks, I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: The choice of tagging really throws the question off-track. It has nothing to do with category theory, or with topos theory. It's a question about logic and perhaps set theory or the axiom of choice. It took me nearly 10 minutes of confusion to understand the question, and it seems I'm not the only one who was confused. Perhaps a better choice of tags can help.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila I did not tag it with category theory or topos theory, and will attempt to untag those two topics.

Comment: You might want to have a look at arXiv:0705.3162 by Maes.

Comment: Quantifier complexity might be more relevant to your intended simplicity than total length.

Comment: @Kaveh: Assuming you mean alternation of unbounded quantifiers rather than plain quantifier count (which is addressed in Joel’s answer), it is easy to see that AC is over ZF equivalent to a $\Pi_2$ sentence, and that it is not equivalent to a $\mathcal B(\Sigma_1)$ sentence. I’m pretty sure it is in fact not $\Sigma_2$, but I don’t know how to prove that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following paper by Kurt Maes is focused on a version of the question at hand here, namely, finding an equivalent formulation of AC in the language of set theory using the fewest number of quantifiers, rather than merely the shortest length. In his main result, Maes finds a 5-quantifier assertion equivalent
to the axiom of choice. The statement is built on the same
statement as in François's answer, but modified to use fewer quantifiers (Maes has five, in comparison with ten for François; but of course François wasn't trying to minimize that quantity).

- Kurt Maes, [A 5-quantifier (\in,=)-expression ZF-equivalent to the Axiom of Choice](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.3162).

Maes's result refuted a conjecture of Harvey
Friedman, which in the introduction the author mentions was stated on F.O.M., that it
would not be possible to state a formulation of the axiom of
choice using only five quantifiers.

Please see Maes's solution in his paper.

When I first heard about the Maes result (August 2004, apparently
an earlier draft of his paper—I haven't checked the
differences), I naturally set myself the task of proving the main result
myself, without looking at Maes's argument. I would encourage the same of all of you---before reading further, try to express AC in the language of set theory using only five quantifiers! Here is what I had come up with (retrieved after digging around in my old computer files):

**Theorem.** AC is equivalent (in ZF) to the following assertion:
$$\forall A\exists B\forall a\in A\, \exists x\forall z$$
$$(x \in a \cap B) \wedge (z \in a \cap B \implies z=x) \wedge (a
\neq B)$$ $$\text{or }\quad(B \in x) \wedge (x \in A) \wedge (a
\neq x)$$ $$\text{or }\quad(B \in A) \wedge (z \notin B).$$

Proof. The point is that in order to get down to only five quantifiers, you have to essentially reuse the quantifiers to cover the various cases. The idea is that clause 1 expresses that $B$ is a selection
set
for $A$, when $A$ is a family of disjoint nonempty sets (plus something extra useful when $A$ is not like that). Clause 2
expresses that $A$ has elements that are not disjoint (at least two
contain $B$). Clause 3 expresses that $A$ contains the emptyset
($B=\emptyset$).

AC easily implies the assertion. If $A$ is a family of disjoint nonempty
sets, then we can let $B$ be a selection set for $A$, and verify clause 1. (note: in order to get $(a \neq B)$ in the case that $A$ is a singleton, we can freely add irrelevant elements to $B$ outside of $\bigcup A$.) If $A$ contains non-disjoint sets, we let $B$ be any element which is
in at least two elements of $A$, and then we can always be in clause 2,
since for any element of $A$ we can find another element of $A$ containing
$B$. Finally, if $A$ contains the empty set, we can set $B=\emptyset$, and
verify always clause 3.

Conversely, suppose that the stated principle holds. To prove AC, it
suffices to construct a selection set for a family $A$ of disjoint
non-empty sets. By replacing $A$ if necessary with the isomorphic copy
$\{\{w\}\times a\mid a \in A\}$, where $w$ has high rank (such as $w=A$ itself), we
may assume that every element of $\bigcup  A$ has the same rank. Thus, every element of $A$ has rank one higher
than this, and every element of $\bigcup\bigcup A$ has rank lower than
this. It follows that no element of $\bigcup A$ is in $A$, and no element
of $\bigcup A$ has itself elements in $\bigcup A$.

For such an $A$, we get $B$ by the stated principle. Note now that Clause
2 implies $B \in\bigcup A$, and clause 3 implies $B \in A$. Meanwhile,
clause 1 implies both that $B$ has an element in $\bigcup A$ and also that
$B$ is not in $A$ (since it implies that $B\cap a$ is nonempty for
some other $a\in A$, while sets in $A$ are disjoint). By our assumptions
on $A$, these possibilities are mutually exclusive.
It follows that $B$ must always be in clause 1, or always in clause 2,
or always in clause 3, regardless of $a$, $x$, and $z$. If clause 3 always
occurs, then $\emptyset\in A$, a contradiction. If clause 2 always
occurs, then $B$ must be in more than one element of $A$, since otherwise
we could let $a$ be that element, and this would contradict the
disjointness of the elements of $A$. Thus, it must be that clause 1
always occurs. In this case, $B$ is a selection set, and so we have
established AC. QED

Although I am not aware of any utility flowing from the fact that AC can be expressed in this manner, it is nevertheless true that proof theory has sometimes made advances by investigating the resource-limited expressive powers of languages.

Answer (score 14):

I suppose you mean a simple sentence in the language of set theory (i.e., with just $=$, $\in$ and logical symbols). I like this version:

> Every family of nonempty pairwise disjoint sets has a transversal.

To say that $A$ is a family of nonempty pairwise disjoint sets, you can use the conjunction of 
$$\forall a(a \in A \to \exists x(x \in a))$$ 
and
$$\forall a \forall b(a \in A \land b \in A \land \exists x(x \in a \land x \in b) \to a = b).$$
To say that $T$ is a transversal for $A$, you can use the conjunction of
$$\forall a(a \in A \to \exists x(x \in a \land x \in T))$$
and
$$\forall a(a \in A \to \forall x \forall y (x \in a \land x \in T \land y \in a \land y \in T \to x = y)).$$

Comment: If $\iff$ counts as a logical symbol, then you can say "nonempty pairwise disjoint sets" faster by saying that two of the sets have a common member if and only if they are equal.

Comment: @François What you give is a formalization of what Russell and others used to call *the multiplicative axiom*, and it fits my bill but I hoped it should be possible to express something even more concise.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest formulation of the axiom of choice in a topos is that **every epi is split**.

$e:X\to Y$ is **epi** if for all $f,g:Y\rightrightarrows Z$, if $f\cdot e=g\cdot e$ then $f=g$.

$e:X\to Y$ is **split** if there is some $m:Y\to X$ with $e\cdot m={\mathsf{id}}_X$.

Comment: That was what I first thought of too. But I wondered whether this is the type of thing OP would disregard (I didn't understand his criteria).

Comment: The question was clearly not concerned with toposes or category theory, and is more clearly not so after usefully suggested edits.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal This answer really has nothing to do with toposes or categories.  It is simple enough to translate the English sentence "every surjection splits" into a string of symbols in first order language of set theory.  It is probably not the shortest in that language, but it is definitely shortest in some other languages.

Comment: @Steven Gubkin That may well be, but I am specifically concerned with the set theoretic setting here, as stated.

Comment: @Steven Gubkin My belief that the answer had to do with toposes or categories stemmed from the edit story of my question, as Paul Taylor misleadingly tagged my question with toposes and category theory,

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal: this *is* set-theoretic!  Although Paul used the word "topos", $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are sets for your purposes.  It might not be the kind of set theory you want to think about, but it's set theory all the same.

Answer (score 0):

We can have a shorter expression for AC by developing suggestions in a comment by Andreas to an answer by François and relying upon a proposal by Emil in the comments section below:

$\forall A(\forall a\forall b(a\in A\wedge b\in A\rightarrow (\exists x(x\in a\wedge x\in b)\leftrightarrow a=b))\rightarrow\exists T\forall a(a\in A\rightarrow\exists x\forall y(y=x\leftrightarrow y\in a\wedge y\in T)))$

Can we do better?

Comment: You may want to add that $\forall a(a\in A\rightarrow\exists u(u\in a))$ to state that $A$ is a collection of non-empty sets.

Comment: I considered such a proviso, but if A is empty the statement holds trivially and we need not regard that as a problem.

Comment: But if $A=\{\varnothing\}$ then $A$ is not empty. But there is no such $T$. (Note that in my comment I pointed that $A$ is a collection of non-empty sets, rather than $A$ is non-empty.)

Comment: You are right! I will mend.

Comment: Wait a minute! If $A=\{\emptyset\}$ then my original antecedent does not hold as $\lnot\emptyset\neq\emptyset$. So I reverse the edit I made.

Comment: Forget the formal statement. Do you agree that the statement that every family of pairwise disjoint sets has a transversal is strictly false is we allow the family to include the empty set? If not, then you should perhaps work again the details of what it means to be a transversal.

Comment: Why should I forget the formal statement? This $is$ about finding the most effective formal statement. The point is that $\forall a(a\in A\rightarrow\exists x(x\in a))$ follows from $\forall a,b(a\in A\wedge b\in A\rightarrow (\exists x(x\in a\wedge x\in b)\leftrightarrow a=b))$.

Comment: The current version is trivially true by taking $T = \bigcup A$.

Comment: Not so, François. Let $a$ and $b$ be distinct members of an A fulfilling the antecedent; then $\lnot\exists(x\in a\wedge a\in b\wedge x\in T)$.

Comment: I was too late to edit the previous comment, so here I correct typos: Let $a$ and $b$ be distinct members of an $A$ fulfilling the antecedent; then $\lnot\exists x(x\in a\wedge x\in b\wedge x\in T)$.

Comment: @François I got your point. I will need to edit.

Comment: I see that the proposal can be amended by letting $T$ be the least set such that $\forall a\forall b(a\in A\wedge b\in A\rightarrow(\exists x(x\in a\wedge x\in b\wedge x\in T)\leftrightarrow a=b))))$. But then the shortness-criterion is not fulfilled, so despite its possible conceptual interest I will vote to close the answer.

Comment: The correct conclusion is $\exists T\,\forall a\in A\,\exists!x\,(x\in a\land x\in T)$, or expanding the abbreviations, $\exists T\,\forall a\,(a\in A\to\exists x\,\forall y\,(y=x\leftrightarrow y\in a\land y\in T))$. No need to make it complicated.

Comment: Thanks Emil!! I was just about to make a more complicated revision ... :)

Comment: Frode, you can certainly shorten it by adding logical symbols like $\exists!$ in the same way that you shortened my version using $\leftrightarrow$. For a definite answer, you would need to clarify the list of logical symbols that can be used. That said, the verification task for a definite answer looks very unpleasant.

Comment: Yes. I wonder whether triadic connectives would achieve anything shorter. Anyway, I am relative to my own purposes satisfied with the present solution.

Comment: Is your formula actually "shorter" than mine? It is most certainly not in any conceptual sense clearer.